# Why is Options button for Photos app missing in iCloud settings?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I've turned on family sharing and want to share photos. There should be a shared album in Photos called "Family" but it's not there. I've found instructions that say I have to use the Options button in the iCloud settings for Photos, but that button doesn't show up for me.
[image: screenshot of icloud apps settings]

How can I get that Options button to show up?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage these settings by opening the Photos app, and opening Photos > Preferences. Select the iCloud tab.

Here is a screenshot of the settings in Mojave – it's similar in later versions of macOS:

[image: Logged in iCloud/Photos.app]

Comment: Unfortunately that has no effect, I already had it turned on. It enables shared albums, but the family shared album is not showing up.